# In SQL, how can I select all parents that have children?

Tags: sql, join, query-optimization, relational-database

Let's say I have two related tables `parents` and `children` with a one-to-many relationship (one `parent` to many `children`). Normally when I need to process the information on these tables together, I do a query such as the following (usually with a `WHERE` clause added in):

```
SELECT * FROM parents INNER JOIN children ON (parents.id = children.parent_id);
```

How can I select all `parents` that have at least one `child` without wasting time joining all of the `children` to their `parents`?

I was thinking of using some sort of `OUTER JOIN` but I am not sure exactly what to do with it.

(Note that I am asking this question generally, so don't give me an answer that is tied to a specific RDBMS implementation unless there is no general solution.)

Comment: Do a `LEFT JOIN` and filter on some child field (Name, for example) being `NOT NULL`. To have each parent only once you will need to use DISTINCT or (if it makes sense), `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks! I got it working with `GROUP BY`, I'm not sure how to use `DISTINCT` though. Also, can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I put earlier in comments:

Solution with `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.parents.id FROM parents p
LEFT JOIN children c ON (p.parents.id = c.children.parent_id)
WHERE children.parent_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.parents_id
```

The same with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.parents.id FROM parents p
LEFT JOIN children c ON (p.parents.id = c.children.parent_id)
WHERE children.parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

It should work in most SQL dialects, though some require `as` when assigning `table aliases`.

The above is **not** tested. Hopefully I made no typos.

Comment: Are the table aliases even necessary in this case?

Comment: Not really. You can use real table names like in your code. I'm just used to have them, since it seems cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest solution that avoids a `JOIN` would be:

```
SELECT * FROM parents WHERE id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM children);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select parent_id,(select count(1) from children where parent_id = x.parent_id)
from parent x where
(select count(1) from children where parent_id = x.parent_id) > 0
```

Comment: Aren't subqueries usually slow?

Comment: put a time and compare. the subquery is just counting rows and it's similar to joining tables.